# formatting headers from report on latex

Tags: report

I'm using the report class to write my PHD.
I'm having trouble with the size of the headers. In one of the chapters, the headers is too close to the numbering. Is there anyway to reduce the font size of the headers? If not, I wouldn't mind removing the chapter title from them, but I'm also having trouble doing that.

Thanks,
Diogo.

[image: Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing font size is not a good idea, as it will yield to inconsistency over the whole document.

Keep in mind that `chapter` has an optional agument

```
\chapter[short title]{long title}
```

If you provide the `short title` it should be used in the headings.

In case that doesn't help you can also set the headings manually for a page; search the KOMA documentation for `\rhead, \lhead` etc.

Comment: The optional short title is the right answer. Beside this i am used to patch the commands (using etoolbox's \patchcmd) producing the headers to replace MakeUpperCase by \textsc (requires to load slantsc package).